# Is there a way to mark a function as only called/callable from a static constructor?

Tags: c#, static-methods, static-constructor, readonly-variable

I have quite a sizeable static constructor for one of my classes, and was wanting to refactor it to encapsulate various bits of the initialization within static functions.

One of the things this static constructor does a lot of is initialize the values of static readonly fields. However, when I try to move these parts into functions, obviously the compiler wont let me as these can only be set in the static constructor. This makes sense as it doesn't know that I only intend to call these functions from my static constructor.

Is there any way around this? e.g. is there some sort of attribute I can put on the functions to tell the compiler the functions are only to be called from the static constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define local functions inside a static constructor;

```cs
public class MyClass {
    public static readonly int Value;
    
    static MyClass(){
        Value = Calc(1);
        
        return;
        
        int Calc(int a) => a;
    }
}
```

The C# compiler will turn those local functions into static methods, with [unpronounceable names](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgzABFATHAsgTwMIBsCGBnPOAbwFgAoOSheKARgDY4AnAUx2AHsA7LNOASy4AXOADUcWAK4sA3OSpx5VOo3TZ8eABQBKUhQVVxUlnAC8cDBIDGm2trn6DixwagB2B08pKngkZawbPzgcbTMAPhDPKgBfchigA===).

Comment: This isn't exactly what I asked for, but it looks like the conceptually closest I'll get if that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `static` and `private` keywords

```
using System;

public class User {
    public static readonly string Name;
    
    static User(){
        Name = GetName();
    }
    
    //`private` function to only be called in static class itself
    private static string GetName() {
       return "Testing";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(User.Name);
    }
}
```

A side note for this solution is that it can help you to prevent outsider functions' calls but cannot prevent being called internally by inner functions.

Comment: This does reduce the risk of the `GetName` function getting called in an undesired way, but it does not guarantee it wont can't be called outside the constructor. It could be called within the scope of the `User` class, in a random function.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Let me mention that in my answer too. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Note that `static` doesn't do anything to prevent access from elsewhere... that's what the `private` part is for. `static` is *just* about the method being related to the type rather than a specific instance of the type.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow, I read your book C# in depth. It's one of my favorite books. By the way, your feedback is true :D

Comment: This is still doing the actual assignment of the static readonly field directly in the static constructor, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I have a lot of these that I'd like to encapsulate in a single separate function, to make the static constructor itself more readable.